# How to write lists as a file attribute using PyGTK

Tags: python, gtk

[image]

A [comment](http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2014/08/emblems-in-nemo/#comment-31100) by the Linux Mint founder stated that file emblems in newer versions of Nemo can be programatically accessed, as seen in the following example using Python and PyGTK:

```
import gio
file = gio.File("/home/guest/Documents/Todo")
emblems = file.query_info("metadata::emblems")
print emblems.get_attribute_as_string("metadata::emblems")
```

Which outputs something in the format

```
[emblem-important, emblem-urgent]
```

The object stored as `metadata::emblems`, as you can see, is a list (I guess of strings). However, in the [PyGTK documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/class-giofileinfo.html) on `Gio.FileInfo`, I can't find a method to access (read or write) attributes of array types.

Is there any method to do this (i.e. reading single emblems or setting new emblems programatically)? If yes, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange that there's no convenience method to do this, but you can call `File.set_attribute` directly, using STRINGV as the type.

```
f.set_attribute('metadata::emblems', gio.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_STRINGV, ['emblem-important', 'emblem-urgent'])
```

Comment: Any idea how to get the value as an array, not stringified?

Comment: As far as I can tell, not on PyGTK. (Maybe `FileInfo.get_attribute_data`? For some reason it doesn't exist on my PyGTK version.) If you can use the new PyGObject (PyGI), there's [`FileInfo.get_attribute_stringv`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/FileInfo.html#Gio.FileInfo.get_attribute_stringv), but note that you can't mix PyGTK with PyGI.

Comment: My version doesn't support `get_attribute_data` either. I'll have a look at PyGI, then.